# 401 response when calling a 307 redirect server

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, urlsession

I have built an iOS app calling a server which only accepts calls from whitelisted IPs (client's security requirement). They have now setup a 307 temporary redirect. I have changed the original root URL to the new redirect address and I am now getting 401 - Unauthorised access errors. Nothing else in the code has changed except for the Urls. I have tested using Postman and the calls work with the redirect address. Does anyone know what is causing this issue? I suspect that the HTTP header is being corrupted and the bearer token lost somewhere in the process.

Here is the HTTP response:

```
<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x600003315840> { URL: https://"API URL HERE" } { Status Code: 401, Headers {
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" =     (
    "*"
);
"Content-Length" =     (
    0
);
Date =     (
    "Wed, 06 Mar 2019 13:50:30 GMT"
);
Server =     (
    ""
);
"Www-Authenticate" =     (
    Bearer
);
"X-XSS-Protection" =     (
    "1; mode=block"
);
```

} }

This is the API caller function:

```
  func callAPI(jsonData: Data, childUrl: String, completionHandler: @escaping (_ success: Bool, _ data: Data, _ response: HTTPURLResponse) -> Void) {

    let access_token = cache.access_token
    let networkHeaders = [ "Content-Type": "application/json", "Authorization": access_token, "cache-control": "no-cache" ]
    print(access_token)
    let dataResponse = Data()
    let urlResponse = HTTPURLResponse()
    guard let url = URL(string: config.rootAPIUrl + childUrl) else { return }

    var request = URLRequest(url: url, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 10.0)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = jsonData
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = networkHeaders


    let session = URLSession.shared

    session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        if error != nil {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completionHandler(false, dataResponse, urlResponse)
                    }
                }
        if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, let data = data  {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
             completionHandler(true, data, response)
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
```

Comment: Make sure you are posting correct `access_token` string. `"Authorization": "Bearer <#access_token#>"`

Comment: Thanks - I am adding the "Bearer" - as I said, everything worked before using the redirect address and the redirect address works when using Postman - just not from my iOS app.

Comment: Make sure you’re sending it again **after** the redirect.  You may have to write a custom redirect handler delegate method to append missing headers from the original request.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of research and help from Apple. The problem was caused by the 'Authorization' value being lost from the header. The solution was to implement a redirect delegate and reattaching the header values. Here's the working code

```
         func callAPI(jsonData: Data, childUrl: String, completionHandler: @escaping (_ success: Bool, _ data: Data, _ response: HTTPURLResponse) -> Void) {

    self.jsonData = jsonData

    let access_token = cache.access_token
    let networkHeaders = [ "Content-Type": "application/json", "Authorization": access_token, "cache-control": "no-cache" ]
    let dataResponse = Data()
    let urlResponse = HTTPURLResponse()
    guard let url = URL(string: config.rootAPIUrl + childUrl) else { return }

    var request = URLRequest(url: url, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 10.0)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = jsonData
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = networkHeaders

    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    var session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)

    session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completionHandler(false, dataResponse, urlResponse)
                    }
                }
        if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, let data = data  {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
             completionHandler(true, data, response)
                    }
                }
            }.resume()
    }


func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, willPerformHTTPRedirection response: HTTPURLResponse, newRequest request: URLRequest, completionHandler: @escaping (URLRequest?) -> Void) {

    let access_token = cache.access_token
    let networkHeaders = [ "Content-Type": "application/json", "Authorization": access_token, "cache-control": "no-cache" ]

    guard let url = request.url else { return }
    guard let jsonData = self.jsonData else { return }

    var request = URLRequest(url: url, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 10.0)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = jsonData
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = networkHeaders

    completionHandler(request)
}
```